How to Implement Row-Level Security in Tableau?
I am attempting to implement row level security in a Tableau workbook, but I have very specific conditions for it. I have five teams (A, B, C, D, and E), each with multiple users, though each user can only be part of one team. In my workbook, I would like to only display data for the team of the user viewing the workbook. I have two exceptions to this rule though. First, any user in Team A should be able to view data for all teams. Second, users in Teams D and E should see data for both D and E.
Some examples of desired output:

When a user from Team A views the workbook, they would see data for all users in all teams.
When a user from Team B views the workbook, they would only see data for all users in Team B. The same would apply for Team C.
When a user from Team D or E views the workbook, they would see data for all users in Team D and E - but not B or C.

To complicate things, the source table (Sales) does not have the Team name for each user so I have to join to a separate table (User) using a unique identifier to get the Team name.
So far, I have tried many strategies to get this to work, but nothing is applying specifically enough to my use-case. I think I need to do something with a parameter and used the steps in this article: 1 to get most of the way there. I currently have a parameter (TeamParam) set up with a filter that allows me to choose the Team from the parameter, however, I still need the row-level security added. One thing I have tried is creating a separate data source for the Users table and applying a filter using the Tableau USERNAME() function to get the LoggedInUserTeam, and creating a parameter with that. I then created a calculated field:
IF LoggedInUserTeam = "A" THEN TeamName ELSEIF LoggedInUserTeam != "A" THEN LoggedInUserTeam END but this didn't work at all, and I couldn't figure out how to handle example number 3 above. In this calculated field, the TeamName field is being pulled from the data source with the Sales table joined to the Users table.
Could anyone please help me achieve this?
